# Enable a single escape sequence in echo

Tags: bash, escaping, echo

In my bash script I need to echo a tab (this happens in a loop)

```
echo -e "$first\t$last"
```

Unfortunately, `$last` might contain some escape sequences, as `\n`, which should be preserved.

Is there any way to enable only the tab escape sequence? I'd rather not decrease performance significantly since my script is slow even now. The loop has many iterations (at least 30000)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash, you can use the `$'` quotes:

```
echo "$first"$'\t'"$last"
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `printf` instead:

```
printf '%s\t%s\n' "$first" "$last"
```

The format specifier accepts two strings `%s` separated by the tab character `\t` and ending with a newline `\n`. Any potential escape sequences within `$first` and `$last` will not be interpreted.

Comment: Isn't printf slower than echo? /edit: it isn't: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58310/difference-between-printf-and-echo-in-bash

Comment: @marmistrz in bash (and I suspect other shells), `printf` and `echo` are both implemented as built-ins, so I wouldn't worry about the difference in performance.